# differentiable map between surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $M$ and $N$ be 2- dimensional surfaces in $\mathbf{R}^3$.

Let $F$ be a function from $M$ to $N$ such that for any coordinate patch $\mathbf{x}$ in $M$ and any coordinate patch $\mathbf{y}$ in $N$, we have

the composite map $y^{-1}Fx$ is Euclidean differentiable as a function from $\mathbf{R}^2$ to $\mathbf{R}^2$.

Can I deduce from the above conditions that

$F\mathbf{x}$ as a function from $\mathbf{R}^2$ to $\mathbf{R}^3$ is Euclidean differentiable?

Answer (score 1):

Yes - using what you've got already, just write $F x =  y (y^{-1} F x)$ and use the fact that the composite of differentiable maps  is differentiable.

Comment: what about domain? Apparently $Fx$ and $yy^{-1}Fx$ have different domains.

Comment: @noot: right, but for any point $x(p) \in M$ there is a patch $y$ such that $p \in \operatorname{dom} (y y^{-1} F x)$, and differentiability is a local property.

Comment: Why isn't   $Fx$ a coordinate patch from $R^2$ into N?

Comment: Why is $y$ necessarily differentiable?

Comment: $y$ is a coordinate patch so differentiable by definition.